# Is this a circuit breaker?

Tags: identification, schematics, symbol

What is this symbol from a single-line diagram of a switchboard?

[image]

It looks like a circuit breaker or a junction box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a voltmeter selector switch (SS).

[image]

*Figure 1. Image source: [Rayleigh](https://www.rayleigh.com/yh-5-3-voltmeter-selector-switch-with-7-positions.html).*

This allows the use of one (single-phase) voltmeter, 0 - 800 V in your case, to monitor phase to phase and phase to neutral voltages.